# SHAREPOIN2007 : Error: The copying of this file failed on deployment

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2007

Hi I have a problem when I deploy my wsp to sharepoint 2007 I get an alarm:

> SHAREPOIN2007 : Error: The copying of this file failed:

And the all my files of the application.

the weird thing is that when I deploy from visual studio I get no alarms and everything looks great.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Which account you are using to deploy the wsp ?

Is that account have the read and Write permission to the folder?

Try to deploy the wsp using the administrative account or with the account which has the 
Identity for the application pool.

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, actually I solved this problem by deleting all files in my feature.xml file, but I still haven't been able to deploy now I'm getting a new alarm: *Error: This solution contains resources scoped for a Web application and must be deployed to one or more Web applications.* is my first time with sharepoint 2007 I haven´t really been able to deploy

Comment: This error message means that the Solution you have created is for  web scoped when you area deplyong it using the Stsadm command then add one more parameter in it -url http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262459(v=office.12).aspx